# What is the default time for the secondary name node to take the backup of name node?

Tags: hadoop

What is the default time(periodic check) for the secondary name node to take the backup of name node ? what is the parameter where i can edit it?

Answer (score 1):

> > fs.checkpoint.period, set to 1 hour by default, specifies the maximum delay between two consecutive checkpoints

More information [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_user_guide.html#Secondary+NameNode).

FYI .... SNN is not for backing up the data from the NN. It's for merging the fsImage and the edits files which are present on the NN.

Comment: Thanks for the details Praveen !! But here are the lines from the Tom White's Hadoop - The Definitive guide book - "The secondary namenode usually runs on a separate physical machine because it requires plenty of CPU and as much memory as the namenode to perform the merge. It keeps a copy of the merged namespace image, which can be used in the event of the namenode failing." From my understanding, the SNN merges the FSI and Editlog (in it's system memory) as new checkpoint and send back to NN and also keep the copy of it in local disk memory. Pls correct me if i'm wrong !!

Comment: SInce you are new to SO, an upvote or marking the answer as correct when appropriae will help you get more response.